# running streamlit app on ec2 nginx subdomain

Tags: python, nginx, amazon-ec2, streamlit

I am facing difficulties running 2 different streamlit apps on 2 different subdomains on a single EC2 server using nginx and tmux.

**Stage 1**: I first tried running only 1 app successfully and my nginx config is as follows:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8501;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        } 
}
```

**Stage 2**: However, when I tried to run 2 different streamlit apps. It does not work. My nginx config file as follows:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location /app {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8501;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        }
}

        location /upload {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8502;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        }
}
```

When I dig into the browser console, the following 2 files are reported as not available.

1. GET http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/static/js/main.4e910df2.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
2. GET http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/static/css/main.f4a8738f.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

These 2 files are actually the site-packages installed for streamlit.

**Stage 3**: I tried to fix the above error by passing root directory into the respective location. As well as adding a slash after the location url. Updated config file as follows:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location /app/ {
                root /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/streamlit;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8501;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        }

        location /upload/ {
                root /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/streamlit;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8502;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        }
}
```

Unfortunately, I still face issue. thought a slightly different one as follows:

1. GET http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/app/_stcore/health 404 (Not Found)
2. GET http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/app/_stcore/allowed-message-origins 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
--server.baseUrlPath=myapp
```

to the streamlit run args, and the app will run on, eg.

```
http://0.0.0.0:8080/myapp
```